# Determining Lat/Long bounds for Cesium Map Tiles

Tags: java, math, latitude-longitude, cesiumjs

I am trying to generate map tiles based on data we have stored in a DB and serve them up to  Cesium using an UrlTemplateImageryProvider.  For each map tile, I need to know the lat/long bounds in order to find matching data.  I'm using the same tile scheme as Google Maps with a request like http://host/tiles/zoom/x/y. Initially I've been using the equations to convert these map tile coordinates into lat/long bounds found here: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#Tile_bounding_box but now I'm wondering if this is not the correct projection to be using.

For starters, all the Web Mercator documentation I see says that Tile 0,0 @ zoom lvl 0 should cover the entire world.  That's not what I see with Cesium (there are 2 tiles at zoom level 0).  That said, my calculations seem to work for zoom levels 0, 1, 2, and 3, but as I go to zoom level 4, the Latitude calculation starts to move south.  If I plot my generated lat, long points on a 2D Google Map, they look correct, but I can clearly see that the tiles requested by cesium have different bounds.  So I am now assuming I'm just using the wrong projection to calculate the tile bounds.

I've also tried the calculations here: http://www.maptiler.org/google-maps-coordinates-tile-bounds-projection/
converting from pixels, to meters, to lat/long but they seem to be the same results as the web mercator calculations.

So can anyone help me figure out how to calculate a Lat/Long bounding box for the tiles requested by Cesium?

Here are the methods I have based on the Slippy Map Tiles:

```
public static Box getLatLonBoundsForTile(int zoom, int x, int y) {
    double longitudeMin = tile2lon(x, zoom);
    double longitudeMax = tile2lon(x + 1, zoom);
    double latitudeMin = tile2lat(y + 1, zoom);
    double latitudeMax = tile2lat(y, zoom);

    Point swPoint = new Point(longitudeMin, latitudeMin);
    Point nePoint = new Point(longitudeMax, latitudeMax);

    return new Box(swPoint, nePoint);
}

public static double getColsForZoomLevel(int zoom) {
    if (zoom == 0) return 2;
    int noTiles = 8 * (int) (Math.pow(4, zoom - 1));
    return noTiles / getRowsForZoomLevel(zoom);
}
public static double getRowsForZoomLevel(int zoom) {
    if (zoom == 0) return 1;
    return Math.pow(2, zoom);
}
public static double tile2lon(int x, int zoom) {
    return x / getColsForZoomLevel(zoom) * 360.0 - 180;
}

public static double tile2lat(int y, int zoom) {
    double n = Math.PI - (2.0 * Math.PI * y) / getRowsForZoomLevel(zoom);
    return Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(Math.sinh(n)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Cesium includes a class [WebMercatorTilingScheme](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/WebMercatorTilingScheme.html) ([source](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/blob/1.19/Source/Core/WebMercatorTilingScheme.js)) that calculates lat/lon values (in Radians) for tiles, with a configurable number of tiles at the root level.

For 3D rendering, typically the tiles are square, with a power-of-2 edge length, for example 256 x 256 pixel images, at all levels.  The globe itself is usually wrapped with a rectangular texture (360 degrees wide, by 180 degrees tall).  To cover this, Level 0 of the tiling scheme is usually two tiles wide but only one tile tall (2 x 1).  The next level is 4 x 2 tiles, then 8 x 4, 16 x 8, etc.

To see this in action in realtime, load the [Cesium Inspector](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Apps/CesiumViewer/index.html?inspector=1), look for some options on the right side of the page, click the little `+` next to `Terrain`, and then put a checkmark on `Show tile coordinates`.  Coordinates are drawn with `L` for level, and `X` and `Y` for position in the tiling scheme.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I was working through implementing the calculations in the WebMercatorTilingScheme when I discovered that I actually wasn't using that tiling scheme at all!  Thanks for pointing out the Cesium Inspector as well.  That's a handy tool!

Answer (score 1):

I just discovered that I was causing the problem in the first place.  I was forcing Cesium to use a GeographicTilingScheme in the UrlTemplateImageryProvider.  My previous config was like this:

```
var layer = new Cesium.UrlTemplateImageryProvider({
    url : '/map/tile/{z}/{x}/{y}?debug=true',
    credit : '© Me',
    tilingScheme : new Cesium.GeographicTilingScheme(),
    maximumLevel : 11
});
```

Which I copied from the example in the [docs](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/UrlTemplateImageryProvider.html). So, now that I removed the tilingScheme from the config, it defaults to a WebMercatorTilingScheme. Here's the new config:

```
var layer = new Cesium.UrlTemplateImageryProvider({
    url : '/map/tile/{z}/{x}/{y}?debug=true',
    credit : '© Me',
    maximumLevel : 11
});
```

Once I did this, I had to remove my assumption of 2 tiles @ zoom level 0 and change it back to 1 and now everything works fine with the methods above! I just changed this method like so:

```
public static double getColsForZoomLevel(int zoom) {
    return getRowsForZoomLevel(zoom);
}
```

So it all came down to the age old lesson of check the simple things first.